# Math equatation issue with negative value in Smarty

Tags: smarty

**Facing problem with negative value for math equation in Smarty**

```
Ex : x=-159 , y =-53.2
{math equation=x-y x=-159.6 y=-53.2 assign="result"}{$result}
```

I have also tried  `format="%.2f"` with math equation.

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the negative values but the missing quotes around the value of argument `equation`.

Because of the missing quotes the function call is parsed incorrectly and it generates a `Warning` at runtime:

> Warning: math: missing equation parameter in *...path-to-file...*

The solution is to put the quotes where they belong:

```
{math equation="x-y" x=-159.6 y=-53.2}
```

If you only need to display the result then you don't need to use `assign`. You will use it, though, if you need to keep the value for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

```
{assign var="result" value="{math equation="x - y" x=-159 y=-53.2}"}
{$result}
```